# Service discovery pattern

Tags: java, node.js, apache-zookeeper

I m actually studying the service discovery pattern but I dont really understand the way how it works.

I have read an article using a library with nodejs called etcd ( http://lukebond.ghost.io/service-discovery-with-etcd-and-node-js/) and it seems easy to use like only setting a pattern url lile /my/service.

Then I have some questions :

- how can I access this service from another nodejs app ?
- how can I do if I want to access /my/service/something, knowing that it s not defined in the service registry and that we admit I dont know at all the API ?

After reading this article, I tried to understand how zookeeper works. With this one, and using a standard library( https://github.com/yfinkelstein/node-zookeeper ), I m facing a problem :

- what is the value I have to set ? In fact with zookeeper, it seems that we have to set a pattern url and a value. What is this value ?
- what are the service children with zookeeper ? What is the aim of this concept ?

Thanks for advance everybody

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/service-discovery-in-a-microservices-architecture/) is a good article about service discovery patterns.
Here are some standard patterns based answers:

> how can I access this service from another nodejs app ?

The service discovery tool like etcd will return you the **list** of endpoints for the service you need. See example [here](https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/0.4.7/etcd-api/#listing-a-directory):

```
{
    "action": "get",
    "node": {
        "key": "/",
        "dir": true,
        "nodes": [
            {
                "key": "/foo_dir",
                "dir": true,
                "modifiedIndex": 2,
                "createdIndex": 2
            },
            {
                "key": "/foo",
                "value": "two",
                "modifiedIndex": 1,
                "createdIndex": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

> how can I do if I want to access /my/service/something, knowing that
>   it s not defined in the service registry and that we admit I dont know
>   at all the API ?

I think you mean "what do I do if /my/service/something is undefined"?
In this case it is all up to the logic of your application. I would think that reasonable way would be retry if you expect that the value will appear at some point.

> what is the value I have to set ? In fact with zookeeper, it seems
>   that we have to set a pattern url and a value. What is this value ?

The value is whatever you want it to be there. With ZooKeeper you might want to use [ephemeral nodes](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.2.2/zookeeperProgrammers.html#Ephemeral+Nodes) for each server node. You can keep data you need to connect to that node inside or just nothing.

> what are the service children with zookeeper ? What is the aim of this
>   concept ?

I think you are referencing to hierarchical structure of ZooKeeper ZNodes. I think "children" in this case will be all nodes which belong to some parent. For example, for nodes /a/b/c and /a/b/d their parent would be /a/b and therefore children of /a/b are /a/b/c and /a/b/d.

Hope this helps.